# What's the difference between A and AAAA DNS records?

Tags: network, dns

Dnsmasq logs show that A and AAAA records are being transmitted/received.

What is the difference between to these two types of DNS records (A and AAAA)? Can either be rejected/dropped/ignored? (Could this be done within Dnsmasq configuration, if possible?). Extra DNS info welcome.

Comment: This is not a question about information security (i.e. off-topic) but a basic question about DNS and networking. But to help: the difference is that A is for IPv4  while AAAA for IPv6 addresses. If you drop any of these you therefore get problems with either IPv4 or IPv6 connectivity.

Comment: I intend to drop one, thank you for clarifying. This question _should've_ been posted in the Network Engineering community, I'm still familiarizing myself with StackExchange. Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! In its current form, your question would probably be downvoted on Network Engineering and most of our other communities. When asking questions here, it's best to show what you have tried to answer it yourself. "What is X?" gets downvoted. "What is X? According to Wikipedia and [book] it does Y, but that doesn't explain Z." gets upvoted. Anyway, welcome to the site, and enjoy your stay!

Comment: Better for server fault.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Sorry about posting to the wrong community

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In DNS, we can have multiple answers and we called them `Resource Records`, shorten as **RR**.

Among the RR, there are A, AAAA, MX, NS,TXT,DS and many others. More details are available [on this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types). The [RFC1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-3.2.2) will also offer you some in-depth technical details (see the file header for more reading materials).

- `A` resource record means IPv4 answer (or entry) for the said domain.
- `AAAA` resource record means IPv6 answer (or entry) for the domain.